# Return value from ActiveRecord::Base.connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using raw SQL via Delayed Job in a Rails application. I realise there are Rails methods for doing this, but bear with me.

The SQL is updating fine, but I would like to review the return value. I have tried inspect, but am getting a "postgres" object.

How can I inspect this object to see the return value or text in order to log it?

```
sql = "delete from primer3_output_pairs where primer_left_sequence is null " +
      "and primer3_output_id in (select id from primer3_outputs where batch_detail_id = #{batch_detail.id})"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).inspect
log("sql delete: #{result}")
```

In the Delayed Job logfile

```
sql delete: #<PG::Result:0x007f98e38834d8>
```

I can imagine the answer to this question will differ between databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and am posting it in case it can help someone else.

Full documentation of the class is here : http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html#method-i-cmdtuples

I just want to get a rowcount, and am not checking for errors. There are other methods for that listed on the linked site.

For a simple rowcount:

```
sql = "delete from primer3_output_pairs where primer_left_sequence is null " +
      "and primer3_output_id in (select id from primer3_outputs where batch_detail_id = #{batch_detail.id})"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
log("sql delete: #{result.cmd_tuples()}")
```